# SSSD: Why do I have to use my previous windows password when I login to the server?

Tags: login, password, ldap, accounts, sssd

I have to change password every third (?) month and I can’t login with the one I currently use in windows but instead the one that I had before this one.

```
[sssd]
domains = (HIDDEN).local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = (HIDDEN).local

[domain/(HIDDEN).local]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = (HIDDEN).LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
#fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ad_domain = (HIDDEN).local
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
debug_level=10
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```

Comment: Providing your OS/release may help us better help you.

Comment: I think it might be ubuntu 20.04 but not completely sure.